# HTML - better use of 'continue reading'

Tags: html

Is there a way in HTML to add a “continue reading” link in the middle of a blog post that displays the rest of the post without going to another page. For example, reader presses “continue reading” and the rest of the post just appears underneath, without having to load the post.

Example: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6404873-penelope-and-the-preposterous-birthday-party

The ‘more’ button does not take you else where, just works within the page.

Thanks

Comment: _just works within the page_...showing a hidden `<span>` (that will make its `<div>` container increase its height).

Comment: The only problem that I see with this is when you also have comments, then the page would become either too long or require another click to show the comments if you're hiding them.

Answer (score 2):

*just works within the page*...showing a hidden `<span>` (that will make its `<div>` container increase its height).

A pretty naive implementation (I'll use jQuery) will be:

```
<div>
    This is a very long post. You read only first paragraph
    but there is much more.
    <a href="#" id="expand-post">Continue reading</a>
    <span id="extra-text" style="display: none">
        You see? I had much more to say about this topic.
    </span>
</div>
```

With this JavaScript:

```
$("#expand-post").click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $("#extra-text").show();
});
```

Now we can do better, that code is pretty easy to become more generic. Let's do it step by step. Firt of all let's remove that ugly IDs, given a general structure like this:

```
<div>
    Preview text.<a href="# class="expand-post">Continue reading</a>
    <span style="display:none">Complete text.</span>
</div>
```

You can have same result assuming `<span>` element is always after `<a>` element to click:

```
$(".expand-post").click(function () {
    $(this).hide().next().show();
});
```

It works but text may come from a DB then you can't setup your markup like that. Let's do another step to make it easier (limited to plain text but it can be fixed to work with HTML too). Actually you don't need to manually split your text, with this markup:

```
<div class="split-text">
    This is a very long text. You'll see a preview only but with a simple
    click you can read the full text. As you can see it can be done with
    few JavaScript lines. 
<div>
```

And this JavaScript you'll get same result (preview text length is set to 32 but this is arbitrary, please note this is completely untested):

```
$(".split-text").each(function (index, element)) {
    var fullText = $(this).text();
    far previewText = fullText.substr(0, 32);

    $(element).empty()
        .append($("<span>").text(previewText)).one("click", function () {
            $(this).replaceWith($("<span>").text(fullText));
        });;
});
```